# How to display only dates with a certain year stored in Room database?

Tags: java, date, android-room, dao

I use an MVVM structure and store dates in a database in a format like 12.05.2020. I want to get all the dates, that have a particular year, 2020 for example. 
My current DAO query looks like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Sorted WHERE date = :date")
LiveData<List<Sorted>> getSortedWhereDateIs(String date);
```

How can I pick out only year or month from a whole date? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use like operator. SELECT * FROM Sorted WHERE date like '%2020'. I am sure there would be some better ways like functions to extract year from date.

Comment: Is there a solution in situation, where I don't know which year the user will select?

Comment: what is the underlying db? MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: It is Room database

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works -
1. Extract the **year** value from the user input
2. Pass the year to your query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Sorted WHERE YEAR(date) = :year")
LiveData<List<Sorted>> getSortedWhereDateIs(Integer year);
```

For month you can use `MONTH(fullDate)`

Answer (score 1):

Your query must be something like that:

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM Sorted where CAST(strftime('%Y', date / 1000,'unixepoch') as INTEGER)  = :yearId)
```

and for month:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Sorted where CAST(strftime('%m', date / 1000,'unixepoch') AS INTEGER) = :monthId")
```

for more details you can check [this blog](https://androiderrors.com/how-do-i-get-certain-row-in-room-database-by-month-and-year/)